# Show product list of specific category not show

Tags: product, product-list, ce-1.9.2.3

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.3 and I want to add a list of products from specific category using this block code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="13" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Also, I add a permission into the blocks permission but is not working.

What can I do?

Comment: You got any error ???

Comment: No. But it seems that I find a solution. I add the code into a static block and then add the block into the homepage. But I want to show the products as a vertical list and they're displayed horizontal. This is my url http://store.hbros.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the view mode with the following layout update:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">     <action method="setData"><key>_current_grid_mode</key><value>list</value></action> </reference>
```

This only works if the setting catalog/frontend/list_mode is set to list(default)/grid or grid(default)/list

Comment: If you don't want to use a layout update than you just can create a custom template.

Comment: Thanks. I change a little bit the template of the product list.

Comment: Did the answer help you with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it works like a charm. Please check permissions of the block (System > Permissions > Blocks). Check if the name is correct and the status has to be Allowed.

Comment: Yes. It is working, but I wonder if it is possible to show a vertical list rather than a grid list?

Comment: See answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106026/22852 for the corrected answer